# creating dynamic navigation sub menu select from database using Codeigniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to create a menu with submenu in codeigniter using ajax I successfully created the menu but i am facing the problem while i will create a submenu. When i click the menu I check it in cosole.log its showing controller is get the details but after that i dont know why its not working. Pls any one solve this issue. thanks in advance
    This is My View Area

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frm_submenu">
               <div class="form-group">
               <label for="menu">Select Menu</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="selectmenuid">
                    <option value="">-- Select Menu --</option>
                    <?php foreach($showData as $show):?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $show->menu_id?>"><?php echo $show->menu_name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
               <label for="menu">Select Sub Menu</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="selectsubmenu">
                    <option value="">-- Select Submenu Menu --</option>
                    </select>
               </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="imagetitle">Image Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imagetitle" id="imagetitle" placeholder="Enter Image Title" required="required">
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                Browse <input type="file" style="display: none;">
              </label>
              </div>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
           </form>
```

This is my ajax area

```
$("#selectmenuid").change(function() {
        var selectmenuid = $(this).val();
        console.log(selectmenuid);
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: selectmenuid,
          url: "<?= base_url() ?>Admin_Creator/SelectSubmenudropdown",
         success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        $('#selectsubmenu').append("<option value='" + data.submenu_id + "'>" + data.submenu_name + "</option>");
        });
        }
        });
        });
```

This is my Controller area

```
public function SelectSubmenudropdown()
   {
       if(isset($_POST['selectmenuid']))
       {
           $this->output->set_content_type("application/json")->set_output(json_encode($this->Model_Creator->getSubmenu($_POST['selectmenuid'])));
       }
   }
```

This is my Model area

```
public function getSubmenu(){  
    $this->db->select('submenu_id,submenu_name');
     $this->db->from('menu,submenu');
     $this->db->where('submenu.menu_id=menu.menu_id');
     $this->db->where('submenu.menu_id', $selectmenuid);
      return $query->result_array();    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive `$selectmenuid` in your model method:

```
public function getSubmenu($selectmenuid){  
    $this->db->select('submenu_id,submenu_name');
    $this->db->from('menu,submenu');
    $this->db->where('submenu.menu_id=menu.menu_id');
    $this->db->where('submenu.menu_id', $selectmenuid);
    return $query->result_array();    
}
```